# Building Android Command Line Executable with Prebuilt Shared Library

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile an Android executable (command line) that calls a method inside a proprietary android prebuilt shared object (.so aarch64)

I'm using an Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64 and I want cross-compile an executable for Android 10 aarch64.

The method is defined from the relative JNI in the following way:

```
public static native int getScore();
```

I build a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int getScore();

int main(){
    getScore();
    return(1);
}
```

Then I develop an Android.mk file like the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mygame
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmygame.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := getscore
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := getscore.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := mygame
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Then I try to compile with:

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk
```

But I get the follwoing error:

```
./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/getscore/getscore.o: In function `main':
/tmp/cross-compile-test/./getscore.c:24: undefined reference to `getScore'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/home/mark01/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/build/core/build-binary.mk:738: obj/local/arm64-v8a/getscore] Error 1
```

Comment: If the shared library was originally written to by called from Java code through JNI, then presumably the `getScore` function is actually named something like `Java_com_foo_Bar_getScore`.

Comment: You right the method is called Java_com_foo_bar_getScore, anyhow unfortunately I have the same undefined reference error to Java_com_foo_bar_getScore()